# Windows form to Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services

I created a program that uses a timer to fill a listbox with data from a file now I wanted to try and change that windows form application to a webservice. I just wondered if anyone could tell me how difficult that may be? I haven't used Web Services before and I have been looking them up and trying to read as much as possible but I can't find out much about timers and webservices. If anyone could give me any advice I would like that very much.

Thanking you.

Comment: IMO it's too broad and vague to fit SO Q&A. Anyway it's pretty easy, not much more than write a plain C# class. Search for a tutorial and you'll be done in few hours. Of course we can't judge how hard it'll be to write **your** web service because we have no idea of what it has to do (return a list of names with a query from a DB or it's service layer of a site like SO?)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the Microsoft Web API.  It should do just what you need.  I've used it, it's great for that stuff.

[Web API Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Comment: No problem at all!  Do you want to mark it as an answer, or else post if you need more info.